# ELKI: LOF score as infinite

Tags: data-mining, elki

What is the generally used and accepted way to handle LOF scores as inifinite in ELKI, due to duplicate points? If LOF scores of ELKI to be used, should such scores be considered as maximum-scores, zeros, or inliers?

Answer (score 0):

The LOF score of a point is infinite if at least one neighbor of a point has reachability distance 0 (because they are duplicate points).

If the point itself has a non-zero reachability, the value is thus infinitely higher than the lrd of the neighbors (or in terms of density: the point is infinitely less dense than the neighbors), so **it is an outlier**.

The proper way of handling this is to **increase k** (minpts) to be larger than the maximum number of duplicate points. If you have too many duplicate points, this usually indicates that using LOF may not be a good idea for this data set. LOF requires that a nearest-neighbor density estimation makes sense on the data, and if you have this kind of problems, the cause usually is the input data, not the algorithm.

Comment: OK Prof. Erich, thanks for the response. I still have one doubt regarding this question. In an answer to one of the questions on LOF scores, you once suggested that :     "What to do if there are more than minPts duplicate points (a literal implementation will yield a division by zero, but for obvious reasons the point should be given a LOF of 1.0)".  If it is to be considered an outlier, the score should be assigned as  >> 1.0. Please bare with me if I am interpreting it wrong, but I think this answer suggests to consider that point as an inlier (due to LOF =1.0), so I am a bit confused here.

Comment: That comment referred to the duplicate point itself. It has the same density as all its neighbors (they are duplicates, and yes, they are inliers), and hence the value is 1.0, not NaN as the 'default' with a division by zero would give; your problem are other points close to the duplicates. These would still get infinity if minpts is too small.